# Zend Framework - Router_Rewrite chaining?

Tags: php, zend-framework, module, routes

I have a project which uses module directory based on custom routes not the default routes. The system loads each module's routes.ini files and add those routes into a Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite router.

```
protected function _initRoutes() {
        $this->bootstrap('FrontController');
        $front = $this->getResource('FrontController');

        $routes = Module_Loader::getInstance()->getRoutes();

        $front->setRouter($routes);
        $front->getRouter()->removeDefaultRoutes();
    }
```

What i am trying to achieve here is to prepend the language code into the uri but chaining with Router_Rewrite is not possible. 
I have a route:

```
[routes]
;Index page
routes.core_index_index.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static"
routes.core_index_index.route = "/"
routes.core_index_index.defaults.module = "core"
routes.core_index_index.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.core_index_index.defaults.action = "index"
routes.core_index_index.defaults.frontend = "true"
routes.core_index_index.defaults.langKey = "route_index_page_description"
routes.core_index_index.defaults.localization.enable = "true"
```

Basically i want the url to look like: http://myhost.com/en/ or http://myhost.com/ which should both direct to this index action of the the homepage controller in the core module.

I can have this appended to the routing rule above as "/([en/]*)" but i don't want the module to care about handling such system-related functionalities.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below configuration. It should work for all your controllers:

```
[routes]
;Index page
routes.core_index_index.route = ":language/:@controller/:@action/*"
routes.core_index_index.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.core_index_index.defaults.action = "index"
routes.core_index_index.reqs.language= "[a-z]{2}"
routes.core_index_index.defaults.frontend = "true"
routes.core_index_index.defaults.langKey = "route_index_page_description"
routes.core_index_index.defaults.localization.enable = "true"
```

You need to set up parameter 'language' every time you use this route.
To make things easier you can set up default value for 'language' like this:

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->setGlobalParam('language', 'en');
```

Comment: Thanks Yarson, this one looks like it'll work but i don't think it will do the trick. Because i am looking for a solution to prevent adding :language to every single route i have in the system. The setGlobalParam is alright but my routes are quite alot. Is there any simple global solution for all routes?

Comment: It's the most straightforward way from my experience. At some stage you might want to add a route without language parameter so this solution will work perfectly because it's flexible. We have 90+ routes on our company website, most of them include :language and are localized (10 languages) and it works just fine.